# Open Source Spreadsheet with Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Is there any good Open Source spreadsheet program that has a solver for linear programs (either included or via an extension) that does a proper sensitivity analysis (shadow prices etc)? It seems like OpenOffice and LibreOffice both don't offer the feature (and do not save the solver's metadata to the spreadsheet file which is quite annoying) and Gnumeric apparently has dropped its support for different reports including the sensitivity analysis.

Are there any good options left (I'd like to propose such a tool to my students as an alternative to Excel)?

Comment: Are you set on a spreadsheet solution or would you consider suggesting R, we used it as undergrads in Biology with success. And it [appears to be gaining traction over SAS](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/02/r-overtakes-sas-and-matlab-in-programming-language-popularity.html)

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't mind using R, GLPK, CPLEX or any other more professional tool. However, some of my (business) students might get scared of anything that goes beyond a normal spreadsheet program :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that google docs [can solve linear programs](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/06/solving-linear-programming-problems.html). Not so sure about the sensitivity analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but Google docs doesn't offer a sensitivity analysis.